# Leaflet: maximum number of layers?

Tags: leaflet

Is there a limit to have many layers you can have in a leaflet map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard limit but performance could be affected by client processor speed, client internet connection speed and the capacity of your server to handle incoming requests. In general I try to keep mine below 10 user-selectable layers. Using well set up base maps instead of lots of overlays should help, also I try to use GeoJSON layers. Performance is great for simple lines or polygons and up to ~ 100 points + labels. Also, when your data changes you don't need to rebuild WMS tiles and it can reduce data transfers.

Answer (score 3):

There is no limit, but from a practical perspective the more layers you have visible, the more the user experience will degrade.

Comment: Regarding simplified user experience. This series of posts by Brian Timoney are very good reads: http://mapbrief.com/2013/02/05/why-map-portals-dont-work-part-i/